# Access Spring beans from Alfresco integration test context

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, alfresco

Now that Alfresco integration tests of custom modules are run using Docker, I wonder how to make additional Spring beans available in this context and how to access existing Spring beans in test classes.

Until Alfresco 5.x, I used to annotate the test class with

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:alfresco/application-context.xml")
```

This made the Spring context available. To make Spring beans from this context available in the test class, I annotated members like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationComponent")
private AuthenticationComponent authenticationComponent;
```

In addition I was able to define additional Spring beans in `src/test/resources/alfresco/extension/test-context.xml`.

Is this the approach to use when writing integration tests for 6.x and Docker?

At least the annotation `org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration` is no longer included in a module build using the Maven 4.0.0 SDK archetype.

[This blog post](https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/blog/2018/04/24/migrating-alfresco-sdk2-projects-to-acs-6) talks about the above mentioned annotations. But the dependencies pulled in by the `pom.xml` created from the SDK 4 archetype don't include these annotations.

A different approach seems to be to only use

```
@RunWith(value = AlfrescoTestRunner.class)
```

on the integration test class. But how do I get the Spring beans like `nodeService` injected into it? And how do I declare and make available additional Spring beans which are part of my custom module and required by the integration test to succeed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Spring context via `AlfrescoTestRunner` as follows:

```java
@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.nodeService = (NodeService) super.getApplicationContext().getBean("nodeService");
}
```

I do the same with custom beans:
`super.getApplicationContext().getBean(MyType.class);`

Since the integration tests run in the repository, all of the Spring context is automatically available.

Note that your test class needs to extend `AbstractAlfrescoIT` for this to work.

An example class may look like this:

```java
package nl.open.mystuff;

import org.alfresco.rad.test.AbstractAlfrescoIT;
import org.alfresco.rad.test.AlfrescoTestRunner;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeService;

@RunWith(value = AlfrescoTestRunner.class)
public class MyCustomIT extends AbstractAlfrescoIT {

    private NodeService nodeService;
    private MyType myType;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.nodeService = (NodeService) super.getApplicationContext().getBean("NodeService");
        this.myType = super.getApplicationContext().getBean(MyType.class);
    }
}
```

In Alfresco SDK 3, you can even add your own Spring XML files under `src/test/resources/alfresco/extension/*-context.xml`. I imagine this still works, but I haven't tried it with SDK 4 myself.

Comment: Is it necessary to have the `IT` at the end of the test class name? Or is this just a convention?

Comment: As it turned out, the `IT` suffix is necessary for the class to be executed as an integration test. The rest of your answer was very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Oh you're right! I do remember encountering that before. Thanks for mentioning it, I'll delete my comment to avoid confusion.